# Dimension of the intersection of k hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra

`V` is a vector space of dimension `n`.
A subspace `W` of `V` is called hyperplane if the dimension of `W` is `n-1`.
Prove that the dimension of the intersection of `k` hyperplanes of `V` is at least `n-k`.

I really don't know how to prove this, can anyone help me?
Thanks for your time

EDIT: I know that n-1 vectors from the basis of V generate W. Let H another hyperplane, so n-1 vectors from the basis of V generate H. The basis of W can be the same of H or there can be only one vector different. So the basis of the intersection is made up at least of n-2 vector. And so on. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps some induction could help: let $\;H_1,H_2\;$ be hyperplanes in $\;V\;$ , so that

$$n\ge\dim(H_1+H_2)=\dim H_1+\dim H_2-\dim(H_1\cap H_2)\implies $$

$$\dim(H_1\cap H_2)\ge 2n-2-n=n-2$$

Assume now the claim is true for $\;k-1\;$ hyperplanes. Let us denote

$$W:=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k-1}H_i\implies$$

$$ n\ge\dim(W+H_k)=\dim W+\dim H_k\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hyp.}}\ge (n-(k-1))+n-1-\dim(W\cap H_n)\implies$$

$$\dim(W\cap H_n)\ge n-k+1+n-1-n=n-k\;\;\;\;\;\square$$